# Inverse limits of groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $\varprojlim {A_i} = P$ with $\mu_{ji} : A_j \to A_i$ be surjective. Show $\pi_i:P \to A_i$ is surjective for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Let $a_i \in A_i$. Then for all $j > i$, the set $\mu_{ji}^{-1}(a_i)$ is non empty.

Take $a = (\mu_{i1}(a_i),\mu_{i2}(a_i), ..., a_i, a_{i+1}, ... )$ where $a_j \in \mu_{ji}^{-1}(a_i)$ for $j>i$

Clearly $a\in P$ since $\mu_{ji}(a_j) = a_i$ and $\pi_i(a) = a_i$.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: What is your index set?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin it's $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Your $a$ need not be consistent as written, because you have no guarantee that $\mu_{j+1,j}(a_{j+1}) = a_{j}$ under your definition; you only required that $\mu_{j+1,i}(a_{j+1}) = \mu_{j,i}(a_j)$. So your $a$ may fail to lie in the inverse limit. If your index set is $\mathbb{N}$, then construct $a$ inductively, by choosing $a_{i+1}$ to map to $a_i$, and then $a_{k+1}$ to map to $a_k$ assuming you alreaady know what $a_k$ is.

Comment: For example, consider the inverse limit of $\mathbb{Z}_{3^n}$ with the obvious projections, and take the element $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Your definition would allow me to pick $4$ for the $\mathbb{Z}_{3^2}$ coordinate, and then pick $1$ for the $\mathbb{Z}_{3^3}$ coordinate, but this element is not in the inverse limit because $1\not\equiv 4 \pmod{3^2}$, even though both map to $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I appreciate the response. I will review this and make another attempt later on